# Cloudwatch API switch role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

In Postman I'm calling the CloudWatch API and the GetLogEvents action.  This works well and I'm able to retrieve logs.  However, I have an AWS Role per AWS environment, so how do I specify a different role to switch to so I can retrieve logs from, for example, my UAT environment?

Many thanks